# SQLDescribeParam fails for all parameter if one cannot determined

Tags: c++, odbc

excerpt: If an sql select statement includes one parameter, which type cannot be determined, SQLDescribeParam does fail with

37000
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Syntax error or access violation

for all parameter, even if their type info should be known...

example:

create table TEST
(
_VARCHAR varchar(100),
_CHAR    char(100)
)

insert into TEST values ('a','a')

insert into TEST values ('ab','ab')

Now,

select * from TEST where _VARCHAR like '%a%'

will return the two rows, but

select *,1 from TEST where _VARCHAR like '%a%'

will return nothing. In the first statement the type of '%a%' can be determined, but in the second because of the additional 1 parameter, both types cannot be determined. That the type info of 1 cannot be determined by SQLDescribeParam is understandable. But why does SQLDescribeParam fail on '%a%' now also?

Sidenote: In cases the type cannot be determined, i do a fallback on the value type of the parameter, here it's SQL_CHAR. And with that i run into another issue. The like statement doesn't work if the column type is SQL_VARCHAR and the parameter is SQL_CHAR. (And i guess SQL_CHAR wouldn't work with SQL_VARCHAR). Fun fact, if i use  _VARCHAR ='a' it doesn't care about the type mixup...

So the question is, why does SQLDescribeParam fail for all parameter when one cannot be determined and how to fix this?

I hope there is somewhere out there who can help me out with this.

thx,
Ronald